# React function to only run once after re-visiting page

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get my function to run once and only once, even when revisiting a page. Take this example (or view this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-oqb8mq?file=src%2FApp.js) demo):

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const TestOne = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect one");
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
      <p>test one</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const TestTwo = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <NavLink to="/test">One</NavLink>
      <p>test two</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/test" component={TestOne} />
        <Route path="/" component={TestTwo} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

When you first visit the `/test` page, the console correctly logs `useEffect one`. Then however, when you visit `/` and then back to `/test`, the console logs again - how can I get it to log only once?

The reason I ask is because in my real, non-demo app, there is data being fetched from an API, and I know it would be best to use fewer resources and not have to re-fetch data from the API whenever that page is re-visited.

Comment: for making the data stay even after refreshing, then you need to use the user's storage either localstorage or in cache/cookies to store your data and then check every time if there's data or not and if there's no data then fetch and store.

Comment: useful comment, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to handle One Time Fetch will be to use :

> USEEFFECT inside const App function

```
const App = () => {
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect one");
  },[]);
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/test" component={TestOne} />
        <Route path="/" component={TestTwo} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

and it will render once until u refresh the page but when navigation around it will not console log it.

Comment: `useEffect` will run on each render if no dependencies are set on it. It should be `useEffect(() => {}, []);`

Comment: yes i forgot to put [ ] in it thanks @mat